# Programmatically selecting second control in tab order

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialog with user controls and is trying to set the control second in line in the tab order to be the starting tab. I.e. when the form is activated the focused control is not actually the one with lowest tab order.
I tried to set this in the constructor using

```
  this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true, false);
```

but 'this.ActiveControl' is null at that time.

anyone got ideas?

Comment: invoke `InitializeComponent()` first

Comment: I am doing that already, doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that in the `Shown` event. This event is invoked as the window is actually shown - at that point, all focussing is already done, all controls have been created and the form is ready. This may not be the case in constructor or `Load`.

Comment: This did indeed tab further, however as I am trying to reach a control within a control (and Shown is only accessable from the dialog) SelectNextControl() is jumping ahead over my child control.

Comment: Are all controls (even the "embedded" ones) accessed correctly if you actually press the TAB key or does this only activate "top level" user controls as well?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: It is not actually a tab control, but a user control. And I have not been able to find SelectedIndex for UserControls.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Your question was a bit unclear to me. I understood you wanted to change the tab programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tabControl1.SelectTab(1);
```

or

```
tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
```

---

Both versions work, when called in the constructor immediately after `InitializeComponent()`. (tested)

---

**EDIT** (after your clarification)

Make this (now second) control the first in the tab order and the previous control (now the first one) the last in the tab order. Since pressing the tab key cycles through all the control, automatically restarting at the beginning after having reached the last one, you should get the desired behavior.

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| 4 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
```

Comment: Changed your question's title in order to clarify.

Comment: After EDIT: the problem with changing the order to 4123 is that higher up (at form level) there is an OK & a Cancel button. These come in between the cycle, disturbing my work.